# Is it safe to mix potassium alum powder with magnesium oil (made from water and magnesium flakes)?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, safety

Will mixing these two together cause a reaction of any sort? If so, is it safe and is there an order in which one should be added to the other?

Comment: Safe for what ? Not to create a bomb, not to kill an ant or safe for touch ? Always add eventually relevant  circumstances and background to prevent wrong assumptions and requests for clarifications.

Answer (score 2):

If you are not sure and you have to do the reaction, try it with small sample of $\ce{Mg}$ such as one flake. $\ce{Mg}$ flakes should react in water and *will* react with potassium alum.

Answer (score 2):

Potassium alum is $\ce{KAl(SO4)2*12H2O}$, the compound that you use to stop bleeding after a bad shave.

I'd say that it won't react, but don't put your health in the hands of strangers on the net.

Answer (score 1):

Finely divided magnesium in water corrodes, liberating hydrogen.  "magnesium oil?"  That is magnesium chloride in water.  It is New Age hype.